# Grouping problem in R to find averages with a condition

Tags: r, group-by

I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(flight_no = c(515,4370,3730,4687,1124), dep_delay = c(-10, 95, -7, 4, 6), is_delayed = c('no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes'), distance = c(1065,628,719,569,2565))
 
#>   flight_no dep_delay is_delayed  distance
#> 1  515       -10          'no'      1065
#> 2  4370      95           'yes'     628
#> 3  3730      -7           'no'      719
#> 4  4687      4            'yes'     569
#> 4  1124      6            'yes'     2565
```

I need to find  the average (mean) delay for flights going over 1000 miles, and the average
(mean) delay for flights going less than 1000 miles filtering for the delayed flights only.

I have tried this

```
df %>%
  filter(is_delayed =='yes') %>%                            # Find delayed flights
  group_by(distance >1000) %>%                              # Group by distance over 1000 miles
  summarise(avg = mean(dep_delay),                    # Summarise and find the mean delay
                        count = n())

Output:
A tibble: 2 × 3
  `distance > 1000`   avg count
  <lgl>             <dbl> <int>
1 FALSE              49.5     2
2 TRUE                6       1
```

It seems correct. is there actually a way to change FALSE and TRUE to 'distance less than 1000' and 'distance more than 1000', respectively?
Maybe there is a better way to to do this.
I'm new to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to change the levels, and `round` to round the values.

```r
df %>% 
  filter(is_delayed == "yes") %>% 
  group_by(distance_1000 = ifelse(distance > 1000, "distance more than 1000", "distance less or equal to 1000")) %>% 
  summarise(avg = round(mean(dep_delay), 2),
            count = n())

#                    distance_1000  avg count
# 1 distance less or equal to 1000 49.5     2
# 2        distance more than 1000  6.0     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may conveniently use `aggregate` for that.

```
aggregate(dep_delay ~ distance > 1000, df, subset=is_delayed == 'yes', 
          \(x) c(mean=mean(x), n=length(x)))
#   distance > 1000 dep_delay.mean dep_delay.n
# 1           FALSE           49.5         2.0
# 2            TRUE            6.0         1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A **base R** alternative using `sapply`.
`with` enables the use of column names without having to reference the data.frame.
`do.call` passes the functions `<` and `>` to the list of distances. Also validating if *is_delayed* is "yes", all applied to the column *dep_delay*.
The resulting list *lis* is then checked for it's `length` and `mean` values.

```
sapply(c("<", ">"), function(x){ 
  lis <- with(df, df[do.call(x, list(distance, 1000)) & 
    is_delayed == "yes", "dep_delay"])
  data.frame(count = length(lis), avg = mean(lis)) 
})
      <    >
count 2    1
avg   49.5 6
```

Keep in mind that this (as per definition in the question) excludes 1000. Use either `<=` or `>=` or add `==` as a third function to include 1000.

```
sapply(c("<", ">=", "=="), function(x){ 
  lis <- with(df, df[do.call(x, list(distance, 1000)) & 
    is_delayed == "yes", "dep_delay"])
  data.frame(count = length(lis), avg = mean(lis)) 
})
      <    >= == 
count 2    1  0  
avg   49.5 6  NaN
```